# How to get the lower bound and upper bound of an element in a BTreeSet?

Tags: rust

Reading the `BTreeSet` documentation, I can't seem to figure out how to get the least value greater than, or greatest value less than an element from a `BTreeSet` in logarithmic time.

I see there is a [`range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html#method.range) method that can give the values in an arbitrary (min, max) range, but what if I don't know the range and I just want the previous and/or the next element in logarithmic time?

This would be similar to `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` in `std::set` in C++.

Comment: This seems to be a useful thing. Maybe you should propose a RFC.

Comment: @Boiethios: I think that the general solution here should use a cursor-API, rather than an iterator-based API.

Answer (score 14):

> but what if I don't know the range

Then use an unbounded range:

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn neighbors(tree: &BTreeSet<i32>, val: i32) -> (Option<&i32>, Option<&i32>) {
    use std::ops::Bound::*;

    let mut before = tree.range((Unbounded, Excluded(val)));
    let mut after = tree.range((Excluded(val), Unbounded));

    (before.next_back(), after.next())
}

fn main() {
    let tree: BTreeSet<_> = [1, 3, 5].iter().cloned().collect();

    let (prev, next) = neighbors(&tree, 2);

    println!("greatest less than 2: {:?}", prev);
    println!("least bigger than 2:  {:?}", next);
}
```

```
greatest less than 2: Some(1)
least bigger than 2:  Some(3)
```

[`BTreeSet::range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html#method.range) returns a double-ended iterator, so you can pull from either side of it.

Note that we are using the very explicit [`Bound`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/enum.Bound.html) operator so that we do not include the value we are looking around.

---

There have been discussions about enhancing `BTreeMap` / `BTreeSet` to have a "cursor" API that might allow you to find an element and then "move around" inside the tree. This would allow you to avoid searching through the tree to find the start node twice, but it has not been implemented.

[A pull request was opened to do so](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/47228), but it was closed because it was deemed that there should be more discussion about how such an API should look and work.

Comment: Note: searching from the start node twice is not necessarily that bad; the complexity is O(N log N) no matter where you start for arbitrary ranges.

Comment: The documentation for this is confusing because you can't tell at a glance if the numbers are indexes or actual items in the container because all of the examples use T=i32, and the way most users are familiar with constructing Range objects is for indexes :P

Answer (score 2):

Well... if you don't mind modifying the current collection and taking a performance hit... it appears that you can use [`split_off`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html#method.split_off) creatively.

```
let mut tree = BTreeSet::new();
tree.insert(1);
tree.insert(3);
tree.insert(5);

let other = tree.split_off(&2);

println!("{:?}", tree);
println!("{:?}", other);
```

Will print `{1}` and `{3, 5}`:

- the lower-bound is the first element of the second range,
- the upper-bound is the first element of the second range if not equal, and the second otherwise.

Once you are done, you can reassemble the tree using `tree.append(other)`.

---

*And yes, it's really less than ideal...*

Comment: Creative solution :'D

Answer (score 2):

If you can change your data structure, you can use [intrusive collections](https://crates.io/crates/intrusive-collections).

You have the desired methods:

- [`RBTree::lower_bound`](https://docs.rs/intrusive-collections/0.7.0/intrusive_collections/rbtree/struct.RBTree.html#method.lower_bound)
- [`RBTree::upper_bound`](https://docs.rs/intrusive-collections/0.7.0/intrusive_collections/rbtree/struct.RBTree.html#method.upper_bound)

Comment: For native rust it works, but my use case is wasm, and I'd have liked it to be a part of core since it is relatively simple to implement if you are already implementing logarithmic search. I'll look into the RFC process.