# Find greater and lower keys in a BTreeSet in a single search

Tags: collections, rust

I would like to be able to find keys in a Rust `BTreeSet` that are strictly lower and greater than a specified key.

For example, given the set `{ "1", "3" }`, and the search key is `"2"` then the answer should be (`"1"`, `"3"`). In the cases either where either  lower or greater value does not exist `None` should be returned.

I can achieve the result that I am looking for by calling the `range()` method on the `BTreeSet` twice.

Is there is a way to do this using a single search, like there is in C++? C++'s `std::set` has a bi-directional iterator:

```
// $CXX -std=c++17 less-than.c++ -o less-than && ./less-than

#include <cassert>
#include <optional>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::optional;
using std::pair;
using std::set;
using std::string;

pair<optional<string>, optional<string>> bounding_box(
    const set<string>& space,
    const string& point)
{
    if (space.empty()) { return {}; }

    optional<string> gt_bound;
    optional<string> lt_bound;

    const auto ge_bound_it = space.lower_bound(point);

    if (ge_bound_it != space.end()) {
        if (*ge_bound_it == point) {
            // lower_bound returned an equal point, use the next one
            // if it exists
            const auto gt_bound_it = std::next(ge_bound_it, 1);

            if (gt_bound_it != space.end()) {
                gt_bound = *gt_bound_it;
            }
        } else {
            gt_bound = *ge_bound_it;
        }

    }

    if (ge_bound_it != space.begin()) {
        lt_bound = *std::next(ge_bound_it, -1);
    }

    return {lt_bound, gt_bound};
}

int main() {
    {
        const auto box = bounding_box({"1", "3"}, "2");
        assert(box.first);
        assert(*box.first == "1");

        assert(box.second);
        assert(*box.second == "3");
    }

    {
        const auto box = bounding_box({"1", "3"}, "4");
        assert(box.first);
        assert(*box.first == "3");

        assert(!box.second);
    }

    {
        const auto box = bounding_box({"1", "3"}, "0");
        assert(!box.first);

        assert(box.second);
        assert(*box.second == "1");
    }

    {
        const auto box = bounding_box({"3", "3"}, "3");
        assert(!box.first);
        assert(!box.second);
    }

    {
        const auto box = bounding_box({"3", "4"}, "3");
        assert(!box.first);
        assert(box.second);
        assert(*box.second == "4");
    }

    {
        const auto box = bounding_box({}, "3");
        assert(!box.first);
        assert(!box.second);
    }
}
```

The `search` method is a bit of a hot spot and I wonder if there is an idiomatic way to do this in Rust.

Comment: Can you share the usecase with us ? I quite curious ;)

Comment: @Stargateur: I am trying to build a replicate physical changes to a large data-structure backed by a logical array. I would like to keep track of changed ranges so that I can send efficient delta updates. The replication is not realtime but async and lazy; if a sub-range has changed multiple times I don't want to send every change, just the minimum set to replicate the difference. The reason I need an exclusive search is to be able to efficiently coalesce adjacent modified ranges.

Comment: Thank, for the use case, I was wondering, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fc5bcd805f7ef9a448402f7d7231d0a7&version=stable&mode=debug) would not be more effective ? Don't hesitate to come in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust)

Comment: @Stargateur: I don't have enough points to join the chat yet. Thanks for the idea, I think my underlying problem is actually more complicated than the question I have distilled it down to. These data-structures and change-sets are not small (100+ GiB) memory efficiency is important here. Given a sequence of operations like: write(objId, pos0, size0); write(objId, pos1, size1); write(objId, pos2, size2)... I need to perdiocally generate the minimum set of write operations that represents the delta, coalescing overwrites to minimize network usage. A bitmap is the other obvious alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in a single search; [you need to call `range` twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50341316/155423).

There have been discussions about enhancing `BTreeMap` / `BTreeSet` to have a "cursor" API. Recently, [a pull request was opened to do so](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/47228), but it was closed because it was deemed that there should be more discussion about how such an API should look and work.

Perhaps *you* will be the one to spearhead the discussion about such an API?

See also:

- [How to get the lower bound and upper bound of an element in Rust BTreeSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48575866/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the PR. I'm new to Rust and am still building a sense of how to build a good Rust API, I can comment on use-cases if that helps the discussion. Coming from C++ it seems like the BTree{Map, Set} lack a bi-directional iterator (or Cursor as also commonly referred to). I can not think of a way to do this in Java that does not involve two searches. The issue is more acute in the case of large trees that involve keys that are expensive to compare.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a cursor API in Rust, as said in Shepmaster's answer. You can sometimes simulate it when your iterator implements `DoubleEndedIterator` with `next()` and `next_back()`.

However, if I understand well what you are trying to do, you do not need this stuff because a set is ordered. You can write your code by going through each pair and stop when the second item is greater than your "point":

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn find_bounds<'a>(set: &'a BTreeSet<&str>, point: &str) -> (Option<&'a str>, Option<&'a str>) {
    let mut it = set.iter();
    let mut lower = match it.next() {
        None => return (None, None),
        Some(s) if *s > point => return (None, Some(s)),
        Some(s) => s,
    };

    while let Some(upper) = it.next() {
        if *upper > point {
            return (Some(lower), Some(*upper));
        }
        lower = upper;
    }
    (Some(lower), None)
}

#[test]
fn tests() {
    let mut s = BTreeSet::new();

    s.insert("a");
    s.insert("c");
    s.insert("t");
    s.insert("g");

    assert_eq!(find_bounds(&s, "f"), (Some("c"), Some("g")));
    assert_eq!(find_bounds(&s, "z"), (Some("t"), None));
    assert_eq!(find_bounds(&s, " "), (None, Some("a")));
}
```

The code is not well written, but it works.

Comment: Won't this change what should be an `O(log N)` operation into `O(N)`?

Comment: @Shepmaster That's true. I didn't see that aspect.